# loginctl same user connected twice: how to kill the right session?

Tags: linux, ssh, session

```
$ loginctl -a list-sessions
loginctl -a list-sessions
   SESSION        UID USER             SEAT             TTY             
       737       1000 wvxvw                                             
        c2       1000 wvxvw            seat0
```

One of these users is me using the UI session, another one is me connecting to this machine via SSH? How do I tell which is which? (I need to kill the other one, but I'd be able to do that once I know which one to kill).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the session with no seat is the ssh session. As mentioned [here](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/multiseat/),

> A session is bound to one or no seats (the latter for 'virtual' ssh
>   logins)

meaning SSH sessions have no seats. Besides, you can further investigate by running:

```
$ loginctl show-session <session-number>
```

the GUI session will have Display set (although that is not always the case), and the SSH session will have `Remote=yes`, `RemoteHost=<IP of connected machine>` and `Service=sshd`

Answer (score 1):

Some poking around showed that `loginctl session-status $SESSION` will print all processes that belong to the session. It is then relatively easy to distinguish between sessions. However, I'd still like to know if there may be some more high-level solution (eg. distinguish between UI session and SSH sessions).